In Zustand, how do I create a Bound Store?
How can I use useBoundStore? I tried the way mentioned in the docs but I get the error:

Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
function component.

export const useBoundStore = create((set) => ({
  ...todoSlice(set),
  ...counterSlice(set),
}));


As the error state there is something wrong the way use call this hook/ or import it, and we need more context to know what happen.
